# How would go about if I just want a temporary function?

Tags: functions, customization, filters, actions

**How would go about if I just want a temporary function?** (It's a converter just for converting Access to Wordpress tables). I want to execute several times so therefore I want it automated, but I don't know how to execute the function after adding the filter in add_action(). After I'm done converting, I will delete the function.

I want to do something like `http://url/index.php?convert`

```
function addcoursecategoriesfromaccess() {
    //code for converting the table
}
add_action('convert','addcoursecategoriesfromaccess');

//If I type http://url/index.php?convert then I want the addcoursecategoriesfromaccess()  to execute
if ($_REQUEST['GET'] == 'convert') {
    do_action('convert');
}
```

I guess I'm missing something very simple, but as a newbie in WP-programming I hope you can help me out :-) I've the code inside functions.php in the theme.

Comment: What you are doing (and the answers) isn't really creating a "temporary" function. You are just hooking a function conditionally. The function will still be defined in the code base until you actually delete it from the '.php' file.

Comment: @s_ha_dum - What do you mean? I wrote that I will delete the function after I've used it. "After I'm done converting, I will delete the function."

Comment: Yes, the "deleting" is what makes the function temporary but you know that. That isn't really what the question is about. If that were it there would have been no question. You seem to be asking how to hook the function conditionally, though honestly this all seems overly complicated for a temporary conversion process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use e.g. the init hook instead. For instance;:

```
if (isset($_GET['convert'])) add_action('init', 'yourfunction');
```

(Come up with a better check, though. ?convert could mean anything. And secure it by checking for user permissions, that it hasn't already run, etc.)

Comment: Thanks a lot! Of course I will secure it more than that :-)

Answer (score 2):

Instead you could hook into init

```
add_action( 'init', 'addcoursecategoriesfromaccess' );
function addcoursecategoriesfromaccess() {
     if ( ! filter_has_var( INPUT_GET, 'convert' )
         return;

     // code here
}
```

Then when you want to run it, just go to the URL as you wrote ( {url}/?convert=1 ) and then the addcoursecategoriesfromaccess will run.

Comment: I think this would work, but I don't believe I should have to execute the function first and then check if convert is set. I believe it should be the other way around.

Comment: @bestprogrammerintheworld If its purely temporary it wont matter if you are going to remove it in the end.

Comment: TRUE! But even if it's temporarily I want to do stuff the "right way". I'm a man of principles! :-) Thanks a lot anyway! You've got +1 from me!